# Redirect after form submitted php

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I have the following code which posts correctly, but i want to redirect to the site index.php page and cannot figure it out. I have searched everywhere and have tried just about everything with no success. Any help appreciated.

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    $query_dupUserCheck = "SELECT tblUser.userKey FROM tblUser WHERE tblUser.username = '".$_POST['username']."'";
    $sqlsearch = mysql_query($query_dupUserCheck);
    $resultcount = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch);

    $query_dupUserCheck2 = "SELECT tblUser.userKey FROM tblUser WHERE tblUser.email = '".$_POST['user_email']."'";
    $sqlsearch2 = mysql_query($query_dupUserCheck2);
    $resultcount2 = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch2);

    if ($resultcount > 0 & $resultcount2 > 0) { 
        print("That Username and Email Already Exists");
    } else {
        if ($resultcount > 0) { 
            print("That Username Already Exists");  
        } else {
            if ($resultcount2 > 0) {    
            print("That Email Already Exists");
            } else {

if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "createAccount")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tblUser (username, password, userTypeKey, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_password2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['userType'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_email'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_ignite, $ignite);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $ignite) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "index.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
header(sprintf("Location : %s", $insertGoTo));
}
}}}
```

The form calls the action with

```
<?php echo $editFormAction;?>
```

Comment: Because of the space in `header(sprintf("Location : %s", $insertGoTo));` between `Location` and `:` try `header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));` that alone will fail. Try it now with that.

Comment: You ca use javascript for do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the call to header; Remove the space between Location and :

```
header("Location: $insertGoTo");
```

OR in your code style:

```
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
```

Answer (score 0):

[**As per my original comment: (link)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662662/redirect-after-form-submitted-php/18662800#comment27483624_18662662)

Because of the space between `Location` and the semi-colon `:`

```
header(sprintf("Location : %s", $insertGoTo));
// ---------------------^
```

Try:

```
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
```

that alone will fail. Try it now with that.

Consult the PHP manual on the `header()` function. **http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php**

Comment: @user2752153 There's something else wrong then and I am unable to use your code to test, but the space between `Location` and the semi-colon is definitely a factor. I will see what else I can do to test with some of your code.

Comment: @user2752153 Maybe it has something to do with `$insertGoTo = "index.php";` ?

Comment: i tried removing that and just put 
header("Location:index.php");
but still no luck

Comment: @user2752153 It stays on the same page because of this `$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` you would need to set your action to another page.

Comment: @user2752153 This `header("Location:index.php");` won't work, you need a space between `Location` and `:` like this `header("Location: index.php");` very important.

Comment: @user2752153 What do you want to do once the form executes, redirect elsewhere or stay on the same page?

Comment: redirect to a different page

Comment: @user2752153 Then create a test file called `test.php` with an `<?php echo "Sent"; ?>` inside that file, and then use `header("Location: test.php");` see how that goes.

Comment: @user2752153 You will have to delete `$insertGoTo = "index.php";` if you're going to use the `header("Location: test.php");`

Comment: still stays on same page.

Comment: @user2752153 Then it has something to do with `$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` then. I don't know what else it could be, as I am unable to test with your code. Try making the form action as another page and use your code inside it for that.

Comment: I ran some tests and header (location:...) seems to only work when placed at the line 1 of the document. Any other ways to redirect?

Comment: @user2752153 The only other ways I know is to use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; ,URL=http://www.example.com/your_page.php">` or do an echo with a link the page.